# Make a function that Replace elements between two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, replace

Need to make a **function** that can replace first **n** elements from *array A* with last **n** elements of *array B*.

arguments in function should be like (*arrayA*, arrayB, **n**)

Works like:

```
int A[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int B[ ] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

function name(A[ ], B[ ], 2)
```

Output:

```
int A[ ] = {9, 10, 3, 4, 5};

int B[ ] = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2};
```

Comment: your effort please

Comment: What do you have so far, what does not work as expected?

Comment: One free hint: your function will also need to take an argument for the size of the arrays, otherwise it won't know what the "last" elements are.

Comment: Start with simpler problems. Write the "hello world". Now add code the to replace A[0] with B[4]. Hard code some more complex examples.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Actually there a few ways beside this way dependent upon whether the array sizes are known at compile-time or not.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio if we consider functions we have to assume that they are not

Comment: Why is this question not already closed? It is clearly a code request.

Comment: @ValetFrost Note, that the self-learning by practice is an important part of learning to code. Don´t let others do the work for you. In this way you won´t come far.

Comment: How do you know the sizes of array A and array B?

Comment: By *replace*, do you mean *exchange*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *mymemcpy(void *a, const void *b, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *ac = a;
    const unsigned char *bc = b;
    while(size--) *ac++ = *bc++;
    return a;
}

void replace(void *a, const void *b, size_t nelem, size_t elemsize, size_t size_b)
{
    const char *bc = b;

    mymemcpy(a, b + (size_b - nelem) * elemsize, nelem * elemsize);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    replace(a,b,3,sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); index++)
    {
        printf("%2d ", a[index]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I would not use it directly as your teacher probably will not believe you.

Comment: Thanks for such a smart answer, will find out how does it works later :)

Comment: "*probably*" is good. ;-)

Comment: Why not use `memcpy` or `memmove` instead of `mymemcpy`?

Comment: @chqrlie I do not know if he is allowed

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_n( int *a, int *b, size_t n )
{
    while ( n-- )
    {
        int tmp = *a;
        *a++ = *b; 
        *b++ = tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int b[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", b[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t n = 2;

    swap_n( a, b + N2 - n, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", b[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 
 9 10  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  1  2
```

Pay attention to that the argument `n` of the function `swap_n` shall be not greater than the number of elements in the array a and in the array b.

Using the function `swap_n` you can exchange any parts of the size `n` of two arrays.  For example to exchange two elements third and fourth of the array a with second and third elements of the array b you could write

```
size_t n = 2;

swap_n( a + 2, b + 1, n );
```

In this case the program output will be

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  7  8  5 
 6  3  4  9 10
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, можешь объяснить этот цикл, пожалуйста `while ( n-- )
    {
        int tmp = *a;
        *a++ = *b; 
        *b++ = tmp;
    }`

Comment: replace not swap

Comment: @ValetFrost You need to exchange n elements of two arrays. So withing the loop that has n iterations n elements are being exchanged. The positions in the arrays from which the exchange starts are specified as pointers to the position in the function calls. For example as the starting position in the array a begins from the first element then you just are passing a.

Comment: @P__J__ See the provided example of the source and result arrays in the question.